# Функция для встроенных типов Java

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте! Увидел в JavaScript подобную конструкцию и хочется узнать, есть ли что-то подобное на Java? Т.е. создание новых функций для базовых вещей

```
Array.prototype.insert = function ( index, item ) {
        this.splice( index, 0, item );
    };
```

Comment: нет, в Java такого нет. Только наследование, только хардкор.

Comment: [Extension функции](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) есть в Kotlin. Это тоже язык для JVM.